# How to optimize this SQL Query (from C#)

Tags: c#, sql

I am newbie to db programming and need help with optimizing this query:

Given tables A, B and C and I am interested in one column from each of them, how to write a query such that I can get one column from each table into 3 different arrays/lists in my C# code?

I am currently running three different queries to the DB but want to accomplish the same in one query (to save 2 trips to the DB).

Comment: Could you elaborate? Do you want each column in a separate array?

Comment: yes. Values from each column in a separate array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@patmortech Use UNION ALL instead of UNION if you don't care about duplicate values or if you can only get unique values (because you are querying via primary or unique keys).  Much faster performance with UNION ALL.

There is no sense of "arrays" in SQL. There are tables, rows, and columns.  Resultsets return a SET of rows and columns.  Can you provide an example of what you are looking for?  (DDL of source tables and sample data would be helpful.)

As others have said, you can send up multiple queries to the server within a single execute statement and return multiple resultsets via ADO.NET.  You use the DataReader .NextResult() command to return the next resultset.

See here for more information:  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz.aspx)

Section: **Retrieving Multiple Result Sets using NextResult**

**Here is some sample code:**

```
static void RetrieveMultipleResults(SqlConnection connection)
{
    using (connection)
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
          "SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName FROM dbo.Categories;" +
          "SELECT EmployeeID, LastName FROM dbo.Employees",
          connection);
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.HasRows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}", reader.GetName(0),
                reader.GetName(1));

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}", reader.GetInt32(0),
                    reader.GetString(1));
            }
            reader.NextResult();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With a stored procedure you can return more than one result set from the database and have a dataset filled with more than one table, you can then access these tables and fill your arrays/lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can do 3 different SELECT statements and execute in 1 call. You will get 3 results sets back. How you leverage those results depends on what data technology you are using. LINQ? Datasets? Data Adapter? Data Reader? If you can provide that information (perhaps even sample code) I can tell you exactly how to get what you need.

Comment: thanks. Given the data can be huge I am not interested in DataSet as it would store a copy in memory. So if you can help me with a DataReader or LINQ example, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you had in mind, but you could do something like this (as long as all three columns are the same data type):

```
select field1, 'TableA' as TableName from tableA
UNION
select field2, 'TableB' from tableB
UNION
select field3, 'TableC' from tableC
```

This would give you one big resultset with all the records. Then you could use a data reader to read the results, keep track of what the previous record's TableName value was, and whenever it changes you could start putting the column values into another array.

Answer (score 0):

Take the three trips. The answers so far suggest how far you would need to advance from "new to db programming" to do what you want. Master the simplest ways first.

If they are three huge results, then I suspect you're trying to do something in C# that would better be done in SQL on the database without bringing back the data. Without more detail, this sounds suspiciously like an antipattern.